# User showing up twice in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, display-names

Try the following: go to the Users page of, say, [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/users). Type `wai` in the search box. Go ahead, I'll wait.

> [image]

Interesting, no?

Not a major issue, just an anomaly. I'm guessing it has to do with the new "search anywhere in the name" functionality?

Comment: Is there any way to put an image in a spoiler tag? :)

Comment: I tried spoiler tag, but it does not work. may be I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I just found out that spoiler tag just change text color to match background color "#EEE", it does not hide the content, so It will not work with images.

Comment: fixed to be deployed some time tomorrow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the bug is because there is two "wai" in the name :D

If you search "ana" in meta, you can see two copies like this too

[image]

Comment: Oh, it's quite obviously due to the same string occurring twice in the username. Well, it's obvious to *me*. A nontechnical user might get horribly confused, though.

Comment: bingo ... that is right